# How can I add wpf browser application in asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

I write a WPF application. but i want to add aspx page like java applet but I don't find any idea. Can you help me?

Please look at: http://img132.imageshack.us/my.php?image=wpfinaspuc2.jpg

Comment: @ykaratoprak: It is better to edit your answer or add comments instead of adding new answers. It keeps the question cleaner.

Comment: T think that; Silverlight is better than wpf browser application is it? if This Question answer is ok : why did  .net developer create wpf browser application? İ want to ask why does  i need wpf browser application instead of  silverlight?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to use your **WPF app in the browser**, you need to create a **XBAP Application**.
   Beware that you need that the client machine has the .Net 3.0 runtime to run your apps and only in Windows.

   This page will be a good start, has tutorials and samples:
   http://www.xbap.org/index.html
2. But, if you want to put a **piece of code inside an existing web site**, like a java applet, you will need to create a Silverlight component, that is not 100% the same as a WPF apps, but you will share most of the code.

   In this case the client will need the **Silverlight runtime** that it is multi-platform (Windows, Mac and Linux)
   Go to this page for a starting point
   http://silverlight.net/GetStarted/

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify? The title suggests you have ASP.NET and want to add WPF (in which case look at xbap or Silverlight), but the question suggests you have WPF and want to add a web page.

If you want to **view** a web page, you should be able to host the `WebBrowser` control in the WPF app. If you want to host a web-server, look at `HttpListener`.

So what do you have, and what exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Either add an XBAP to your webpage, or rewrite the functionality using Silverlight and embed the app on your page.

Silverlight would be the preferred choice.

It can be embedded;

```
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">....</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

Scott Guthrie has a Silverlight tutorial blog series here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-1-creating-quot-hello-world-quot-with-silverlight-2-and-vs-2008.aspx

I agree with Jamie and Marc, Silverlight is probably your best option if you want something similar to a Java Applet.